# How to filter the query for firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, filtering

I am trying to implement a search filter for the firestore database list in flutter,`widget.selectedValue` is the value of the category to filter with it is received from another StatefulWidget successfully but does not change the query, and hence the results are not received as desired. the below method `getquery()` is called in `initState()`, but it doesn't work, How should I make sure when the below method is called in `initState()` it changes the query as required

```
getquery(){String category = widget.selectedValue;

    if (category != null){

      query = widget._firestore.collection("items").where("itemcategory", isEqualTo: category ).orderBy('timestamp', descending: true);   }
    else {
       query = widget._firestore.collection("items").orderBy('timestamp', descending: true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Simple answer: you'll have to update the query outside of `initState`. Long answer: if the `widget.selectedValue` is passed around from widget to widget, you will have to use some form of state management to pass around the query, for which there are a bazillion options in flutter. Provider is one very common solution to similar problems, but there are also many more (like GetIt).